# How to integrate datetimepicker with ASP.NET localisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using Trent Richardson's datetimepicker extension for JQuery, obtained via NuGet:
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Trent's documentation says that you can create a localised datetimepicker like this:

```
$('#basic_example_4').timepicker(
    $.timepicker.regional['es']
);
```

I'm attaching a datetimepicker to an ASP.NET TextBox by setting the CssClass property on the TextBox, and having the JavaScript attach the datetimepicker by selecting on the CSS class:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.calendarStartDateTime').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
            controlType: 'select',
            oneLine: true
        });
    });
</script>
...
<asp:TextBox ID="StartDateTime" runat="server" CssClass="calendarStartDateTime" meta:resourcekey="StartDateTimeResource1"></asp:TextBox>
```

My ASP.NET page declaration sets `culture="auto"` and `uiculture="auto"` so that all the ASP.NET elements pick up culture settings from the browser settings (and so I can use ASP.NET Resources to localise text).

I would like the datetimepicker to also automatically apply localisation based on the browser settings, consistently with how the server-side components are being localised. How do I achieve this? Do I need to insert an ASP.NET tag into the Javascript, something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.calendarStartDateTime').datetimepicker({
            $.timepicker.regional[<% magic happens here %>],
            controlType: 'select',
            oneLine: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Or should the browser culture be detected in pure JavaScript?

---

EDIT: based on @smirnov's answer, my final code for the timepicker was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.calendarStartDateTime').datetimepicker(
            $.extend(
                {},
                $.datepicker.regional['<%= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName %>'],
                $.timepicker.regional['<%= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName %>'],
                {
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                    timeFormat: '<%= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern %>',
                    controlType: 'select',
                    oneLine: true
                }
            )
        )
    });
</script>
```

This code correctly merges the regionalisation settings for jQuery's built-in datepicker, Trent Richardson's timepicker properties, and some custom settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName`

As timepicker seems to use country code as a value for regional, try

```
...
$.timepicker.regional['<%=System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName%>'],
...
```